# Setup Interstaste font in CygWin/TeX Live

Tags: fonts, cygwin

I have some trouble to setup a font under Cygwin/TeX Live, any idea on how to solve that will be welcome.

I setup a new Cygwin 1.7.x on a PC, it comes with TeX Live, and I try to install an additional font called "Interstate". That font is delivered as a `tar.gz` file, so I unpacked that file like below and got that file/folder struct.

```
$ tar -zxvf Interstate-fonts4-texlive.tar.gz

usr/share/
usr/share/texmf/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/a_2fwcon.enc
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/a_2mvdqo.enc
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/a_c353pt.enc
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/a_e7miqr.enc
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/a_phwclb.enc
usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lcdftools/a_xdkkoc.enc
usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/lcdftools/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/lcdftools/Interstate/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate.map
usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/lcdftools/InterstateLight/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/lcdftools/InterstateLight/InterstateLight.map
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ly1--lcdfj.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ly1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-t1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-t1--lcdfj.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-t1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ts1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ly1--lcdfj.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ly1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-t1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-t1--lcdfj.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-t1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ts1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ly1--lcdfj.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ly1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-t1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-t1--lcdfj.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-t1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ts1.tfm
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/Interstate/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold.pfb
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-BoldLCDFJ.pfb
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/InterstateLight/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic.pfb
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-ItalicLCDFJ.pfb
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light.pfb
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-LightLCDFJ.pfb
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/Interstate/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ly1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-t1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/Interstate/Interstate-Bold-tlf-ts1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ly1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-t1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-Italic-tlf-ts1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ly1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-t1.vf
usr/share/texmf/fonts/vf/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate-Light-tlf-ts1.vf
usr/share/texmf/tex/
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lcdftools/
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lcdftools/InterstateLight/
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lcdftools/InterstateLight/Interstate.sty
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lcdftools/InterstateLight/LY1Interstate-TLF.fd
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lcdftools/InterstateLight/T1Interstate-TLF.fd
usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lcdftools/InterstateLight/TS1Interstate-TLF.fd
```

To finalize the font setup, i wrote a small script to run the command below, but it return an error message:

```
    mktexlsr: Updating /etc/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/share/texmf-site/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Done.
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /home/abuisson/.config/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
Creating new config file /home/abuisson/.config/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/home/abuisson/.cache/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/home/abuisson/.cache/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/home/abuisson/.cache/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/home/abuisson/.cache/texmf/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
        Interstate.map (in /home/abuisson/.config/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)

        Did you run mktexlsr?

        You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
          --syncwithtrees.
```

Below, the command I ran to get the error message.

```
# create texmf-site if non-existent
if [ ! -d /usr/share/texmf-site ];
then
    mkdir /usr/share/texmf-site
fi

# update paths, including the new fonts
mktexlsr

# font installation
updmap --enable Map Interstate.map
updmap --enable Map InterstateLight.map
```

Answer (score 1):

I found at least a "workaround". As the .tar.gz file inflate its folder and file structure in `/usr/share/texmf/`, I realize that TexLive updmap and kpath search path for map, sty etc in `/usr/share/textmf-site/` because it's the path I got when i ran:

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

So the easiest solution is to duplicate(copy) the whole `texmf` folder content into the `texmf-site` folder using:

```
cp -r /usr/share/texmf/* /usr/share/texmf-site/
```

and call again my font install script.